# How to manually controll animation progress in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am planing a "tutorial/demo app" that should show the user how to control other apps/software by presenting a screenshot walkthrough, e.g.

- Show in Screenshot1
- Fade in a label above the Screenshot that tells the user "Touch this button"
- Run som click/touch animation above the button
- Fade in Sceenshot2
- Zoom in to some area of the Screenshot
- ...

Creating this using basic `UIView` animation is not a big deal:

- Start animation to show the lable
- Run click/touch animation with some delay
- ...

However the user should be able to manually control the progress of this animation, move forward and backward, pause, etc. Just as if the presentation would be a movie that can be controlled using the timeline.

If the user does not do anything, the animation simply runs and some view (e.g. a `UISlider`) shows the progress. But if the user touches the slider the animation stops. By moving the slider back or forth, the user can rewind or fast forward the presentation.

**How can this be done?**

Stopping the animation at is no problem, but `UIView` animation do not have any properties to control the progress, do they?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303010/how-to-stop-and-reverse-a-uiview-animation?rq=1 check this answer might help you.

Comment: I think you should take the x (or y?) position of the user's touch in the view. Based on that, you can calculate a "progress" (from left to right -- 0% 100% for example). Then you could change the animation based on the progress.

Comment: @Ramon Of course, this would be an alternative to setting the progress using a UISlider. However this does not answer/solve the actual question: how to pause, rewind, forward, etc. a running animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this framework https://github.com/IFTTT/RazzleDazzle